# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, windows-xp, openssh

I just set up openssh on a Windows XP machine and I'm trying to access that from a remote machine.  Although I can telnet into the remote machine and also execute "ssh localhost" when actually on the remote machine, when I try and SSH in from my Mac, I get …

```
davea-mbp2:~ davea$ ssh developer@remote_ip
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have added my IP to the /etc/hosts.allow file …

```
#
# hosts.allow   This file describes the names of the hosts which are
#               allowed to use the local INET services, as decided
#               by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' server.
#
#               CYGWIN note: if you use a software firewall (such
#               as ZoneAlarm or the "Windows Firewall" in Windows
#               XP), you must also open a 'hole' at the proper
#               port for the services you enable below.
#
ALL : localhost 127.0.0.1/32 [::1]/128 [::ffff:127.0.0.1]/128 : allow
ALL : PARANOID : deny
sshd: ALL : allow

sshd: my_local_network_ip
sshd: my_ip
```

Here are the contents of my /etc/hosts.deny file …

```
#
# hosts.deny    This file describes the names of the hosts which are
#               *not* allowed to use the local INET services, as decided
#               by the '/usr/sbin/tcpd' server.
#
ALL:ALL EXCEPT localhost:DENY
```

Any ideas how I can modify these files or potentially do something else to allow me to login?